# solution to 1st order non linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I have to solve the O.D.E

> $$x\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)-25=y^2$$

---

My attempt at a solution so far is:

$$x\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}\right)=y^2+25$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{(y^2+25)}=\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$

let $u:=y/5$

$$\implies \frac{\mathrm du}{5(u^2-1)}=\frac{\mathrm dx}{x}$$

Integrating both sides then yields

$$(1/5)\arctan(y/5)+C=\ln(x)+C \implies \arctan(y/5)=5\ln(x)+C$$

$$ \implies \arctan(y/5)=5\ln(x)+C \implies y/5=\tan(5\ln(x)+C)$$

$$\implies y/5=\tan(5\ln(x)+C)$$

> $$y=5\tan(5\ln(x)+C)$$

if someone could please tell me if this is correct or not that would be great, and if it is incorrect any hints,tips or tricks would be hugely appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Your solution $y(x)=5 \tan(5 \ln x+C)$ is correct !

Comment: that's great , for some reason when i was doing this last night i got the idea that it was non seperable into my head (assuming that non-linear meant non seperable), so i thought there was something wrong with this solution XD. Must have been the tiredness. thanks though Fred !